# How to put an lwjgl app into a Javafx/swing canvas

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans, jframe, lwjgl

is it possible to put the lwjgl display onto a canvas created in a Jframe Form? I'm using the Netbeans IDE v8.2 and lwjgl 2.9.3. Thanks for the help! Heres some of my code from the DisplayManager which is called from the MainLoop.

```
public class DisplayManager{

private static final int WIDTH = 800;
private static final int HEIGHT = 600;
private static final int FPS_CAP = 120;

private static long lastFrameTime;
private static float delta;

public static void createDisplay() {

    ContextAttribs attribs = new ContextAttribs(3,2).withForwardCompatible(true).withProfileCore(true);


    try { 

        Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
        Display.create(new PixelFormat(), attribs);
        Display.setTitle("Coffee Beans V1");
        Display.setParent(EditorGUI.canvas1);
        new EditorGUI().setVisible(true);



    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GL11.glViewport(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    lastFrameTime = getCurrentTime();

}
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried and how it isn't working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, via org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.setParent(java.awt.Canvas).

Comment: I set the canvas to be visible and then I used Display.setParent(canvas), but the lwjgl window just opens alongside the gui window, instead of inside it. I'll update my post adding some of my code from my DisplayManager.

Comment: Haha I fixed it, it was a stupid mistake I made. I just ordered some things incorrectly. Thanks for the help!